# My javascript (for randomizing css3 animation delays) doesnt fire in IE 10 and Opera...Jsfiddle Included

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I have encountered this issue and am desperately trying to fix it since days. What I did now is create a jsfiddle with an explanation of the entire issue and a working example code for you to see.

http://jsfiddle.net/jEN8X/7/

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var e, t = document.querySelectorAll("div.bounceInDown");
    for (var n = 0, r = t.length; n < r; n++) {
        e = Math.round(Math.random() * 7e3) + "ms";
        t[n].style.animationDelay = e;
        t[n].style.WebkitAnimationDelay = e
    }
}, false)
```

What am I doing wrong? It doesnt seem to work in IE 10 or Opera.

Edit: It seems that IE10 only fires the script when refreshing the page.

Comment: Could it be your use of **webkit only API calls**? like `WebkitAnimationDelay` =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera seems to start the animation before you noticed it, during the page load - Increase the `animation-duration` to see that clearly ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jEN8X/18/)). Waiting for `DOMContentLoaded` will be too slow, at least for applying the `animation-delay` on the already running animation.

To fix that, start the animation only after you set the random delay. For example, you can add the `animation-name` at that time ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jEN8X/17/)).

Comment: Not sure about IE10, I can't test there but suspect similar issues.

Comment: Thank you Bergi. That was very kind. Also I love your explanation. I hope this will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your example in JSFiddle this error appears to be the CSS line:

`@keyframes bounceInDown{0%{opacity:0;transform:translateY(-2000px)}60%  {opacity:1;transform:translateY(30px)}80%{transform:translateY(-10px)}100%{transform:translateY(0)}}.bounceInDown{-webkit-animation-name:bounceInDown;-moz-animation-name:bounceInDown;-o-animation-name:bounceInDown;animation-name:bounceInDown}`

I'd expect the above to use the non moz (`animation-name` instead of `moz-animation-name`) and webkit (`animation-name` instead of `webkit-animation-name`) prefixes.

Also, what's the significance of the `@-o-keyframes` statement?